# rails refreshing scope request for google api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, google-api, omniauth, google-api-client

I have a rails app with google-api-client and omniauth-google-oauth2 gems. I would like to integrate google calendar. I tried to do the authentication with the code below, but it failed.

The problem is when I change the scope let's say to: `scope: ['email']` or even to `scope: ['hahahaha']` I get the same response from google which is shown below the code. After playing with it for a while I gave up and waited some time then tried again and I got a new error response. I tried to change the code but I got stuck again this time with another error. Is there a time limit or why the response doesn't het updated right after changing the code?

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY'], ENV['GOOGLE_API_SECRET'], {
    scope: ['email, profile, calendar'],
    access_type: 'offline'
  }
end
```

error message from google:

Error: invalid_scope

Some requested scopes were invalid. {valid=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar, [invalid= profile, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/email,]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [omniauth-google-oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) docs `scope` should be a string with comma separated scopes. But you're using an array in your code. So `scope: "email, profile, calendar"` should work.

As to response changing over time, do you use `Spring` in you Rails app? `Spring` allows you to load Rails app faster by preloading it during the first run. Then, when you run `rails` again, it uses this preloaded app. After changing app configuration you have to restart application for the changes to come into effect. If you just restart `rails` it won't work, because Spring is still running an app in memory. So, if you use `Spring` you have to restart it as well after changing app configuration, like so:

```
spring stop
rails s
```

Comment: Jeiwan, thanks to the gems https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2 I gotta use this way (I mean something similar), just not sure yet which version should work at the moment. I could try all the combinations/versions I've found if google sent back new responses right after chaning my code. Don't you know why I don't get new response when I change the code?

Comment: Jeiwan, thx it works now. I don't use spring and restarted the server everytime. Maybe the array caused this weird problem.